# Determine whether, for any set A, it is true that $P(\bar{A})= P(U) - P(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working on a easy enough logic question, however I'm having trouble proving or disproving it's validity. The question goes as follows:

> Determine whether, for any set A, it is true that $P(\bar{A})= P(U) - P(A)$
> where "U" is the universal set and "P" refers to the power set.
>
> If it is true prove it, if it is not, give a counterexample.

I can make a counterexample easily enough by assigning set values to A and U but I'm not sure how to disprove using set-builder notation or other methods etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you've found a counterexample (as one can), then that's enough to disprove the statement. There's no need to make it fancy.

Comment: Alright, was looking for a second opinion so thanks! :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713987/is-it-true-that-mathcalpac-mathcalpu-%e2%88%92-mathcalpa?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you using universal sets it is necessary to determine the axioms you working with. You question refers to universal sets and complements axioms, leading to a set of axioms described in this [Book](http://phil.gu.se/logic/books/Holmes:Elementary_Set_Theory_with_a_Universal_Set.pdf).

The statment is false simply because: 
$U \neq P(\bar{A}) \bigcup P(A)$

since for : 
$B \in P(A), C \in P(\bar{A})$ 
we also know that: 
$B \subset A, C \subset \bar{A}$

Therefore: 
$B\bigcup C \not\subset A$ and $B\bigcup C \not\subset \bar{A}$

And therefore:
$B\bigcup C \notin P(A)\bigcup P(\bar{A})$

But
$B\bigcup C \in U,P(U)$

leading to: 
$U \neq P(\bar{A}) \bigcup P(A)$
or
$P(\bar{A})\neq P(U)−P(A)$